# IE9 window.opener problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a window `A`, `A` will pop a window we called `B`, `B` will submit data to server, and then redirect `B` to domain same with `A`.

My question is at the last step,seems when the server does 302 redirect, the window object in `B` will lost the opener property under IE. how do i solve it? thanks for advice

**Update:**

What i want to do is, when `B` redirect back to the same domain as A, `B` will transfer some data to `A`. I must use 'B'.opener to get a reference of  `A`. It works as expected in chrome but not in IE.

Comment: What do you want exactly reach?

Comment: @reporter the question is updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by myself, to approach that. I did the following step:

1. Store a reference of B when B pops up in A
2. Set a timer in A keep tracking if B's location is readable and the domain is same with A
3. If B's location.host is readable and same with a again, read the value then close B

Answer (score 1):

I found the same question (maybe) on my test site with IE9.
but it's running correctly on my production site with the same code.

And I found that if A and B are running with different IE security settings
(in my case A is local network, B is internet ) ,  it will cause this problem.

If I change IE security settings, let A became to internet settings, 
no this problem any more.

Answer (score -1):

I enabled "Protected Mode" in "Local intranet" settings of the internet explorer (Tools->Internet Options), and worked perfectly.

Regards,
Alvaro.